# ServiceStack 3.9.61 NuGet package not working

Tags: c#, servicestack, nuget

ServiceStack 3.9.61 NuGet package not working. 
Cannot find Route attribute class.
Looks like old version of child/sibling assemblies eg ServiceStack.Interface = v3.0.9.
Nuget buggy - suggest not using (it pulls down dodgy verion, when uninstalled package, it left some pieces.  Had to manually fix- recommend using manual add-references).

Comment: Please try to make your question easier to read - remove "I'm new to XXXXXX", "thank you notes", general whining, and random historical notes like "Couldn't get it to work Friday ".

Answer (score 3):

Actually there was something wrong with NuGet versioning after applying the following [version restriction](http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/versioning) to restrict dependencies to only look at packages between **3 < 4**, e.g:

```
<dependency id="ExamplePackage" version="[3,4)" />
```

Unfortunately when doing this NuGet started to think that somehow **v3.0.9** was the latest version. The only way I could solve it on my end was to delete all the packages below **v3.9.10** which has now been done for all ServiceStack projects so you should no longer have this problem.

Another option is to reference the copy of the same NuGet packages which are deployed on MyGet at: https://www.myget.org/F/servicestack/

Which you can do by [adding the above NuGet feed in](http://docs.myget.org/docs/how-to/register-myget-feeds-in-visual-studio):

```
Tools > Options > Package Manager > Package Sources
```

This also works as only the latest packages are available on the above feed (MyGet has better control and management of NuGet packages).